# Wordpress tax_query "and" operator not functioning as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of **image** with a custom taxonomy called **image_tag** (it's hierarchical like categories). Here are some examples of the tags that might be used:

```
Structure (id: 25)
- House (id: 56)
- Skyscraper
Nature
- Animal
- Plant (id: 41)
```

So, I want to drill down through the images by selecting multiple tags in conjunction with the "and" operator. For example, finding all photos with **plant**s and **house**s.

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'image',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'terms' => array(41, 56),    // IDs of "plant" and "house"
      'operator' => 'and',
    ),
  ),
);
```

That works fine, the problem begins when I try to include the parent terms, for example:

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'image',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'terms' => array(25, 41),    // IDs of "structure" and "plant"
      'operator' => 'and',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Then I get no results. I'm guessing that because I'm using the "and" operator, Wordpress doesn't include the children of the "Structure" term. Does anyone have an idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Two quick questions:
1) Just to sure. Can you 100% confirm there are posts that should be returned?
2) Have you tried explicitly setting `include_children` to `true`? I believe there at least used to be a bug that required you to do that (despite it normally being the default).

Comment: Ok: 1) yes, there are posts that are tagged with both of those terms (or children of them), and  2) yes, I did experiment with `include_children` as well, and sadly that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Good to know. My next guess was @hubert-popp's answer below. I'd try that.

Comment: Yeah, the solution from @hubert-popp does return the correct result.  It's odd to have more than one query from the same taxonomy, but if it works, it works.  :)  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it should look like this:

```
'relation' => 'AND',
   array(
         'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => array( 25 ),
         ),
         array(
         'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => array( 41 ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: You forget to close 'terms' and 'operator' by ' like this

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'image',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms' => array(25, 41),    // IDs of "structure" and "plant"
      'operator' => 'in'
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make a difference for me. (I think `term_id` is the default for that `field` setting.)

Comment: but use my code cuz you have some errors in your code like 'terms you must close it like this 'terms' also 'operator'

Comment: Thanks, I fixed those typos. This is just a sampling of the code I've used, not the full example, so I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_args = array(
 'post_type' => 'image',
 'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms' => array(25, 41),    // IDs of "structure" and "plant"
      'operator' => 'in'
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I had a similar problem, give this a try!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is valid, but unfortunately not in the way I'm looking for. This solution returns images that are in **structure** and images that are in **plant** (which broadens the search).  What I need is to narrow the search by returning images that have both **structure** and **plant** tags (or children of those tags).  ...I don't know if that makes sense the way I'm describing it, lol